# Stop first <li> being draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

This is my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/michelejs/PeS2D/560/

How can I stop the first `<li>` being draggable?

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('li').removeClass('ui-corner-bottom');
$('ul')
    .addClass('ui-corner-top')
    .removeClass('ui-corner-all')
    .sortable({
        'containment': 'parent',
        'opacity': 0.6,
        update: function(event, ui) {
            alert("dropped");
        }
    });
});​
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the option `items` in the `.sortable()` widget method.
Combined with the jQuery selector `gt()`, you could easily get what you are looking for.

This works for me ([jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/PeS2D/563/)) :

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('li').removeClass('ui-corner-bottom');
    $('ul')
        .addClass('ui-corner-top')
        .removeClass('ui-corner-all')
        .sortable({
            'items': '>li:gt(1)',
            'containment': 'parent',
            'opacity': 0.6,
            update: function(event, ui) {
                alert("dropped");
            }
        });
});​
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `items` property:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('li').removeClass('ui-corner-bottom');
    $('ul')
        .addClass('ui-corner-top')
        .removeClass('ui-corner-all')
        .sortable({
            items: 'li:not(:first)',
            'containment': 'parent',
            'opacity': 0.6,
            update: function(event, ui) {
                console.log(ui)

            }
        });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ppRJL/

Answer (score 2):

try this.
http://jsfiddle.net/PeS2D/561/

I added an extra class called header to the first li and then [there is a function called `cancel`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-cancel)

to save people a click:

[Cancel] Prevents sorting if you start on elements matching the selector.
Code examples:
Initialize the sortable with the cancel option specified:

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({ cancel: "a,button" });
```

Get or set the cancel option, after initialization:

```
// getter
var cancel = $( ".selector" ).sortable( "option", "cancel" );

// setter
$( ".selector" ).sortable( "option", "cancel", "a,button" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Just read the documentation : http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items

The `items` option allow you to specify a selector for sortables elements.

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PeS2D/562/

You can set it to be like this

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('li').removeClass('ui-corner-bottom');
  $('ul')
    .addClass('ui-corner-top')
    .removeClass('ui-corner-all')
    .sortable({
        'containment': 'parent',
        'opacity': 0.6,
        update: function(event, ui) {
            alert("dropped");
        },
    items: 'li[id!=heading]'  
    });
});​
```

then add an `id` to your first li

```
 <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading" id="heading">Re-order</li>
```